# warning: Ecto.Repo.insert_all/3 is undefined or private

Tags: compiler-errors, elixir, warnings, ecto, undefined-function

***(Please note: Noob here so please ELI5, thanks.)***

Code Snippet:

```
defmodule Wallet do
    use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :arbit,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
    alias Ecto.Repo
    #use Genserver

    require ArbitDB.WalletBalance

    def refresh_db do
        updated_balances = liquid_holdings()
        Repo.insert_all(WalletBalance, updated_balances, 
            on_conflict: :replace_all_except_primary_key, conflict_target: :value_USD)
    end



$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Compiling 1 file (.ex)
warning: Ecto.Repo.insert_all/3 is undefined or private
```

What's causing this warning and what's the correct resolution? Thanks for taking a moment to help out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Ecto.Repo.insert_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#c:insert_all/3) is a *callback*. That said, it is to be implemented by *your* repo module.

[ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) would call it whenever she desires she needs to insert several records into your repository.

The good news is if you don’t need some very specific implementation, [ecto](/questions/tagged/ecto) [provides a naïve one](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.3.3/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L263-L265) for you (don’t be scared by the word “naïve,” it’s fine in 99% of cases.)

That said, you need to call `insert_all/3` on *your repo*, which calls `use Ecto.Repo` (the latter macro is the one which would *inject* all the [default implementations and more](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v3.3.3/lib/ecto/repo.ex#L153-L342).)

---

*Sidenote:* I am unsure what are you actually trying to achieve, the rest of the code seems to be inconsistent as well, but since `Wallet` is the guy who calls `use Ecto.Repo` and hence who plays the role of `Repo` in your application, calling `Wallet.insert_all/3` (or not fully qualified `insert_all/3` since we are inside the very same module,) would be a great start to dig further.